# Symfony 2.8 form dynamic generation choice_label raw twig

Tags: php, forms, symfony, twig, symfony-2.8

I want to render raw form label, I have the following form entity type

```
    $builder
        ->add('subscriptionBilling', 'entity', array(
            'class'         => 'AppBundle\Entity\SubscriptionBilling',
            'data_class'    => 'AppBundle\Entity\SubscriptionBilling',
            'choice_label' => function ($allChoices, $currentChoiceKey) {
                    return '<p>Categories <strong>'.$allChoices->getNoOfCategories().'  number</strong> '.$currentChoiceKey.'</p>';
            },
            'choices'       => $options['packages_allowed'],
            'data'          => $options['selected_subscriptionBilling'],
            'multiple'      => false,
            'expanded'      => true,
            'required'      => true,
            'label'         => false,
         ))
         ;
```

and my twig

```
{% autoescape false %}

{{form_label(form_categories.subscription.subscriptionBilling)|raw}}
{{form_widget(form_categories.subscription.subscriptionBilling)|raw}}

{% endautoescape %}
```

but i get this html

```
<p>Categories <strong>5 number</strong> 0</p>
<p>Categories <strong>10 number</strong> 1</p>
<p>Categories <strong>25 number</strong> 2</p>
<p>Categories <strong>10 number</strong> 3</p>
```

Comment: Provide error you are getting.

Answer (score 1):

I finally created a form theme which extends bootstrap form layout

```
{% extends 'bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig' %}
{% block radio_label %}
    {# Do not display the label if widget is not defined in order to prevent double label rendering #}
    {% if widget is defined %}
        {% if required %}
            {% set label_attr = label_attr|merge({class: (label_attr.class|default('') ~ ' required')|trim}) %}
        {% endif %}
        {% if parent_label_class is defined %}
            {% set label_attr = label_attr|merge({class: (label_attr.class|default('') ~ ' ' ~ parent_label_class)|trim}) %}
        {% endif %}
        {% if label is not same as(false) and label is empty %}
            {% set label = name|humanize %}
        {% endif %}
        <label{% for attrname, attrvalue in label_attr %} {{ attrname }}="{{ attrvalue }}"{% endfor %}>
            {{- widget|raw }} {{ label is not same as(false) ? (translation_domain is same as(false) ?  label|raw : label|trans({}, translation_domain)|raw ) -}}
        </label>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock radio_label %}
```

and my twig

```
 {% autoescape %}
 {{form_label(form_categories.subscription.subscriptionBilling)}}
 {{form_widget(form_categories.subscription.subscriptionBilling)}}
 {% endautoescape %}
```

and it seems to work